# Python: Save specific method in object

Tags: python

How can I assign a specific method to an object in Python that is not part of the class.
I want to have a class that executes a specific method that is not part of the class but is part of the file.
I want to reduce if-else loops with this.

```
class RangeStrategie(object):
    x0 = 0
    x1 = 0
    name = ""
    functions = ???

    def __init__(self,x0,x1,name,func):
        self.x0 = x0
        self.x1 = x1
        self.name = name
        self.functions = func

    def execute(self, y):
        if self.x0 <= y and y <= self.x1:
            print("--> Execute {} Option {}-{} mit {}".format(self.name,self.x0,self.x1,y))
            self.functions()
```

It is possible?

```
def pse():
   print("Test")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   RangeStrategie(1,9,"Einer",pse())
```

Comment: `RangeStrategie(1,9,"Einer",pse)`

Comment: Yes, just change this line `RangeStrategie(1,9,"Einer",pse())` to this `RangeStrategie(1,9,"Einer",pse)`

Comment: Just give the function name, no parentheses

Comment: Is there a reason you made x0, x1, name, functions both class and instance variables?

Comment: Thank you! - I learned to program with Java, probably because of that.